# UnboundLocalError at /register/ local variable 'form_value' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

**I'm trying to get into it the register page but i cant**

**views.py**

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_value = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form_value.is_valid():
                form_value.save()
                user = form_value.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was create for {}'.format(user)) 
                return redirect('login')

            context = {'form_key':form_value}
            return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

**Traceback**

```
File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\le\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\le\Desktop\django-course\Django(02-09-21)\crm1\accounts\views.py", line 26, in registerPage
    context = {'form_key':form_value}
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'form_value' referenced before assignment
```

**Maybe have problem with indentation, please help me**

Comment: Where's the form for `GET` request you need to define that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the form object for `GET` requests.

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_value = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form_value.is_valid():
                form_value.save()
                user = form_value.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, 'Account was create for {}'.format(user)) 
                return redirect('login')

        form_value = CreateUserForm()    # < --- here    
        context = {'form_key':form_value}
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)
```

---

You can check whether the user is authenticated or not, by using `decorators` more reusable way. [ref](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/07/working-with-django-view-decorators.html)

decorators.py

```
# checks whether the user is logged in and control accessing to register page
def unauthenticated_user(views_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return views_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func
```

in views.py

```
@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):
    ...
```